# user.displayName not showing on react firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const [pass, setPass] = useState('')
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const auth = getAuth();
const inputHandler = e => {
  setUser(e?.target.value)
}
const passHandler = e => {
  setPass(e?.target.value)
}
const nameHandler = e => {
  setName(e?.target.value)

}
const toggleLogin = event => {
  setIsLogIn(!event.target.checked);
}
const signUpHandler = (e) => {
  signUp(user, pass)
    .then(result => {

      setUserName();
      history.push(url)

      // console.log(url)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(error.message)
      // ..
    });

  e.preventDefault()
}
const signUp = (user, pass) => {
  setIsLoading(true)

  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user, pass)

}
useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user)

      // console.log("auth changed",user.email)
    } else {
      setUser({})
    }

    setIsLoading(false)
  });
}, [auth])
const setUserName = () => {

    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      displayName: name
    });
```

Before displayName property being updated  its redirecting to the route it came from. Is this happening for asynchronous nature?

I'm trying to set the displayName property on the navbar.displayName is getting set but not showing on ui, but showing after when I refresh the page. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please reformat your code so it's easier to understand your question.

Comment: You've declared `setUserName` `async` and you don't await it in the calling scope. It's not clear what you are expecting the code to do. What is `updateProfile`? Why do you invoke the navigation *before* you call `setUserName` and in doing so why wouldn't you expect the navigation to occur first?

Comment: Actually I was given the task to debug the code. I already tried making the setUserName a normal function instead of async function also called setUserName() before history.push(url) but didn't worked.

Comment: What is `setUserName`, or `updateProfile` supposed to do? What is the expected behavior? Are you really just asking why the navigation occurs first?

Comment: the project is using firebase email password authentication system to implement  sign In and sign Up method . setUserName function is setting the displayName property of firebase auth using udateProfile method, which is taken from the registration form.updateProfile is a firebase provided method to update displayName property. And  the application is supposed to redirect the user on private route after sign Up and update the name on navbar. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I see. Where does `name` come from in `updateProfile`? Can you update your question to include a more complete/comprehensive component code example?